# Check All checkbox should be unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

```js
    function toggle(source) {
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('options[]');
      for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
      }
    }
```

```html
<form class="unsubscribe_form" action="process.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-1" value="Option1">
  <label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-2" value="Option2">
  <label for="checkbox-1-2"></label>Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-3" value="Option2">
  <label for="checkbox-1-3"></label>Option 3
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-4" value="Option3">
  <label for="checkbox-1-4"></label>Option 4
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-5" value="Option3">
  <label for="checkbox-1-5"></label>Option 5
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" id="checkbox-1-6" value="All" onClick="toggle(this)" />
  <label for="checkbox-1-6"></label>All
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Unsubscribe" />
</form>
```

When I check the All checkbox, of course, it will mark all the checkboxes, but once I uncheck one checkbox, the All checkbox is still checked. This should be unchecked. How should I do that using JS?

Comment: you don't have any event handlers on the other check boxes, is there code missing here?

Comment: Add a method (e.g. onClick) on each checkboxs  to uncheck/check checkbox-1-6.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `onchange` event handlers to every checkbox and check inside if the "All" checkbox should be checked (all checkboxes are selected) or unchecked (at least one is deselected). For example like this:

```js
var checkboxes =  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByName('options[]')),
    allCheckbox = document.querySelector('input[value="All"]');

checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    checkbox.onchange = function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
            allCheckbox.checked = false;
        }
        else {
            var checked = checkboxes.filter(function(check) {
                return check.checked;
            });
            if (checked.length === checkboxes.length) {
                allCheckbox.checked = true;
            }
        }
    };
});

function toggle(source) {
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
```

```html
<form class="unsubscribe_form" action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-1" value="Option1">
    <label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>Option 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-2" value="Option2">
    <label for="checkbox-1-2"></label>Option 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-3" value="Option2">
    <label for="checkbox-1-3"></label>Option 3
    <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-4" value="Option3">
    <label for="checkbox-1-4"></label>Option 4
    <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-5" value="Option3">
    <label for="checkbox-1-5"></label>Option 5
    <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" id="checkbox-1-6" value="All" onClick="toggle(this)" />
    <label for="checkbox-1-6"></label>All
</form>
```

Note that I converted checkboxes collection to array with `[].slice.call` in order to use convenient array methods. Simple for loops can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
function toggle() {
  // getting a reference to all the 'name="option[]" elements:
  var options = document.getElementsByName('options[]'),
    // a reference to the 'all' checkbox:
    all = document.getElementById('checkbox-1-6');

  // if the changed checkbox is the 'all':
  if (this === all) {
    // we iterate over all the options checkboxes (using
    // Array.prototype.forEach()):
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(checkbox) {
      // and we set their checked property to the checked property
      // state of the 'all' checkbox:
      checkbox.checked = all.checked;
    });
  } else {
    // otherwise we set the 'all' checkbox to the state of
    // the Boolean returned by Array.prototype.every(),
    // which returns true if all checkboxes evaluate to
    // the condition within the function, otherwise false:
    all.checked = Array.prototype.every.call(options, function(checkbox) {
      return checkbox.checked;
    });
  }
}

// getting a NodeList of all the elements of 'class="unsubscribe-checkbox"':
var options = document.querySelectorAll('.unsubscribe-checkbox');

// iterating over them, again with Array.prototype.forEach()
// and assigning a change event-listener, which will execute the
// name function:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(opt) {
  opt.addEventListener('change', toggle);
});
```

```js
function toggle() {
  var options = document.getElementsByName('options[]'),
    all = document.getElementById('checkbox-1-6');
  if (this === all) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(checkbox) {
      checkbox.checked = all.checked;
    });
  } else {
    all.checked = Array.prototype.every.call(options, function(checkbox) {
      return checkbox.checked;
    });
  }
}

var options = document.querySelectorAll('.unsubscribe-checkbox');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(opt) {
  opt.addEventListener('change', toggle);
});
```

```html
<form class="unsubscribe_form" action="process.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-1" value="Option1">
  <label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-2" value="Option2">
  <label for="checkbox-1-2"></label>Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-3" value="Option2">
  <label for="checkbox-1-3"></label>Option 3
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-4" value="Option3">
  <label for="checkbox-1-4"></label>Option 4
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" name="options[]" id="checkbox-1-5" value="Option3">
  <label for="checkbox-1-5"></label>Option 5
  <input type="checkbox" class="unsubscribe-checkbox" id="checkbox-1-6" value="All" />
  <label for="checkbox-1-6"></label>All
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Unsubscribe" />
</form>
```

You may notice that I've removed the `onClick` attribute from the 'all' checkbox, in preference of unobtrusive JavaScript, where the event-handlers are assigned via the JavaScript itself (which ordinarily makes for more easily-maintained code, as the arguments to be passed to a given function are assigned in the code itself, rather than having to be separately updated in the HTML).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).